# Can I share the dishwasher or other appliance lines from adjacent room lines?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I've read the posts by Tim and Mitch posted in Sept. I'm remodeling the kitchen with all new wiring. I've never had a dishwasher, but will at some point. I only have enough space for a 24"er, so probably not a huge draw. There's a sink to the right. To the left is a 6" space with a hinged door. I had planned on placing the dishwasher appliance receptacle in there for quick access. Being that it's within 6ft of water I had planned on a GFCI. I am short on available lines in my 100 Amp box, so I was wondering if I could tap into a new line from the adjacent living room? That line is already GFCI, 20A/120V, 12-GA with four outlets in the lvg room, one receptacle on the front porch, and one in the attic only to plug in a short length of of roof de-icer cable. These outlets are rarely used.
  I was also wondering about using that same living room line, or another nearby low usage line (furnace), to share with the kitchen gas stove and overhead exhaust filter?

Answer (score 1):

The most relevant NEC section is:

> **210.23(A)(2) (2)Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place.** The total rating of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires, shall not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.

Roof icer plus dishwasher sounds like a bad combination.  Putting all your fixed items together (e.g. furnace) is reasonable.